# An example from the TikZ manual re the /tikz/graph/parse key

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I will list two LaTeX manuscripts. The first one, which is the example given in the manual to demonstrate the usefulness of the `/tikz/graph/parse` key, compiles successfully, whereas the second one fails to compile. After listing the first manuscript and showing its output, I will argue that the second manuscript is equivalent to the first one. Clearly this argument is false, but I don't know why.

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript, which is essentially a copy of the example in the end of subsection 19.3.2 ('Syntax of Group Specifications') of section 19.3 ('Syntax of the Graph Path Command') of chapter 19 ('Specifying Graphs') of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a (p. 265).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
    \def\mychain#1{
        \def \mytext{1}
        \foreach \i in {2,...,#1} {
            \xdef\mytext{\mytext -> \i}
        }
    }
    \tikzgraphsset{my chain/.style={
        /utils/exec=\mychain{#1},
        parse/.expand once=\mytext}
    }
    \tikz \graph { [my chain=4] };
\end{document}
```

The resulting rendered picture is (not to scale)

[image: A TikZ graph]

I'll explain the output as best I understand it.

1. The `\tikzgraphsset` command simply executes its keys with the path prefix `/tikz/graphs` (the `\tikzgraphsset` command is described in p. 262). So the key `/tikz/graphs/my chain` becomes an abbreviation that expands to `/utils/exec=\mychain{#1}, parse/.expand once=\mytext`.
2. Next the `\graph ...` command is executed. The only thing to do is to process the group options (`[my chain=4]`). The group options are executed with the path prefix `/tikz/graphs` (this is described in p. 264). So the key assignment `/tikz/graphs/mychain=4` is executed. This expands to `/utils/exec=\mychain{4},/tikz/graphs/parse/.expand once=\mytext`.
3. Now the assignment `/utils/exec=\mychain{4}` is executed. This key simply executes the assigned value (this key is described in p. 893 in the 'Key Management' chapter), so the macro `\mychain{4}` gets expanded.
4. As the last step, the assignment `/tikz/graphs/parse/.expand once=\mytext` is executed. The key handler `.expand once` causes `\mytext`'s replacement text, namely `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`, to be assigned to `/tikz/graphs/parse` (the `.expand once` key handler is described in p. 890 in the chapter 'Key Management' chapter). The effect of assigning to the `/tikz/graphs/parse` key is that the assigned value is inserted at the beginning of the current group, as if you had entered it there (`/tikz/graphs/parse` is described in p. 265.)

In conclusion, the above manuscript should be equivalent to the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
    \def \mychain#1{
        \def \mytext{1}
        \foreach \i in {2,...,#1} {
            \xdef\mytext{\mytext -> \i}
        }
    }
    \tikz \graph { \mychain{4} 1->2->3->4 };
\end{document}
```

And yet the last manuscript fails to compile, and `pdftex` reports the following error message:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\mychain #1-> \def \mytext 
                           {1} \foreach \i in {2,...,#1} { \xdef \mytext {\m...l.11     \tikz \graph { \mychain{4} 1->2->3->4 }
```

I will appreciate it if someone can explain not only why the second example fails, but, more importantly, how the first example works. I'd like to be able to predict how similar examples will play out.

Comment: Where is `\mytext` in the graph ? You just defined it

Comment: The original example is expanding stuff and then inserting it in the relevant place. In your example, the stuff is just being inserted as replacement tokens, since that's what a macro does. But you can't use, say, `\def\mytext{1}` here in the argument. It works in the first case because stuff gets expanded first. If you define `my chain` in the first example as `parse=\mychain{#1}` rather than using `exec`, then you have something closer to your second example.

Comment: @percusse: I get the same error message when I replace `1->2->3->4` with `\mytext`.

Comment: it's not clear why you think the forms are equivalent. if you can do `\tikz{...}` that does not mean that you can do `\tikz{\def\tmp{...}\tmp}`

Comment: graph parser changes the reading of the code. There are all kinds of differences inside the graph parser than TikZ which is also different than TeX completely. So it is perfectly normal if the parser is not expanding the macros on its way because it is constantly looking for characters to understand the context. The source is full of `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` conditionals. So the answer is just it's by design.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I tried to explain in detail in my post why I thought the forms were equivalent. In my opinion (which I realize is false, but I don't know exactly why), the equivalence follows from the definitions in the manual.

Comment: @EvanAad but would you expect the forms I used in my comment to be equivalent? You can not replace the argument of tikz (or any tex command in general) by commands that do definitions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is a very good question. I'm not sure how TikZ handles non-TikZ TeX code that is embedded inside a TikZ picture. Off the top of my head I'd say that yes, I'd expect the forms you used in your comment to be equivalent.

Comment: That basically is why you are expecting the wrong result,  you are not distinguishing expandable from non expandable operations. Your second form inserts extra `\def`  that typically does not work `\def\tmp{1}\tmp` will typeset `1` but `\setcounter{equation}{\def\tmp{1}\tmp}` will not set the counter to 1. whereas `\def\tmp{1}\setcounter{equation}{\tmp}` will. the difference is all about where expansion occurs

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Fair enough. So let's say this explains, in general terms, why the 2nd manuscript produces an error. But the more important question is: how exactly does the 1st example work? How does TikZ process the option `mychain=4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough outline* of how the TikZ "engine" processes the path

```
\graph { [my chain=4] };
```

Let's say the graph parser is called `\graph@parser` (it is not, this is just for the sake of illustration). Then the above statement expands to

```
{\graph@parser [my chain=4] };}
```

In other words, the two tokens `\graph {`  were replaced by the `\graph@parser` control sequence, and the entire statement was then surrounded by a TeX group.

So now TeX opens a new scope, and proceeds to work on the following input stream:

```
\graph@parser [my chain=4] };}
```

When the parser sees the `[`, it replaces the entire `[...]` construct with
`\pgfkeys{/tikz/graphs/.cd,...}`, and parsing resumes after execution of the options. In other words, the last code snippet expands to

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/graphs/.cd,my chain=4}\graph@parser };}
```

The `/tikz/graphs/.cd` key signals that keys with a relative path (or 'partial path' to use the manual's terminology) are to be interpreted relative to the base path `/tikz/graphs`. So the last code snippet expands to

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/graphs/my chain=4}\graph@parser };}
```

Since `/tikz/graphs/my chain` is a style, it is replaced by its "replacement text" after substituting the assigned value 4 for the parameter #1, so the last code snippet expands to

```
\pgfkeys{/utils/exec=\mychain{4},/tikz/graphs/parse/.expand once=\mytext}%
    \graph@parser };}
```

As mentioned in the original post, this expands to

```
\mychain{4}\pgfkeys{/tikz/graphs/parse/.expand once=\mytext}\graph@parser };}
```

`\mychain[4}` expands ultimately to `\gdef\mytext{1->2->3->4}`. So the macro `\mytext` is saved in TeX's internal state, and the last code snippet reduces to

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/graphs/parse/.expand once=\mytext}\graph@parser };}
```

As mentioned in the original post, this expands to

```
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/graphs/parse=1->2->3->4}\graph@parser };}
```

The action of the key `/tikz/graphs/parse` is to insert its argument just following the `\graph@parser` control sequence. So the last code snippet expands to

```
    \graph@parser 1->2->3->4};}
```

The overall effect of all these expansions is as though the original path (`\graph { [my chain=4] };`) had been replaced by

```
{%
    \gdef\mytext{1->2->3->4}%
    \graph{1->2->3->4}%
}
```

This, in turn, is equivalent to

```
\def\mytext{1->2->3->4}%
\graph{1->2->3->4}
```

---

* To be clear: this means that I'm not telling the full story, and that I'm telling some white lies to make the presentation clearer and cleaner.

Comment: You've moved options out of the group to which they are restricted. If you write `\graph` -> `\path graph`. If you move the options out of the group, they apply to the whole path. But that's not how it works.

Comment: @cfr: The full path for `parse` is `/tikz/graphs/parse`, so it would be included in `<options 2>` and after the re-write be part of the options passed to the `\graph` command.

Comment: Missed that you said that above. But the main issue still remains. `\path <bunch of stuff> graph [<options>] {<spec>} <another bunch of stuff>;` has to make sense, because `\graph` just is `\path graph`. In your example, `<options>` is empty. The only options are part of the `<spec>`. But even if you had `<options>`, it still isn't equivalent to move then outside the scope of the `graph`. They don't apply to the rest of the path.

Comment: Try e.g. `\tikz \path [draw=blue] (0,0) -- (1,1) graph [edges=red] { [my chain=4] } graph [edges=<->, nodes={y=-1}]  { 5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 } (8) edge [green, <-, thick] ++(0,-1)  ;`.

Comment: Or `\tikz \path [draw=blue] (0,0) -- (1,1) graph [edges=red] { [my chain=4] } graph [edges=<->, nodes={y=-1}]  { [/tikz/orange] 5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 } (8) edge [green, <-, thick] ++(0,-1)  ;` and note what does and doesn't turn orange ....

Comment: @cfr: I've revised my post in light of your comments.